# For all location in array x equal to z, sum corresponding location in array y

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, sum, lookup

I am looking for a function that sums all values in columns (F, L, R ... n) if their corresponding values in rows (C, I, O ... n-3) equals eg. "A".

If if was only a few columns I would use sumif for each column, but i have to repeat this 600 times for 50 different values ( A, B, C ...)

I have tried SUM(IF(C9:O57="A";F9:R57)) which worked at first, but in my 'real document' it returns "0", when I copy it.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slM2m.png)

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to recommit the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after copying. In any case, the non-CSE `=SUMIF(C9:O57,"A",F9:R57)` will give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get it one number = really sum all the tables for values next to "A", then you could use something like this

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(OFFSET(F:F;0;6*(ROW(1:50)-1));OFFSET(C:C;0;6*(ROW(1:50)-1));"A"))
```

(quite possibly you have different regional setting so you might need to change `;` into `,`)
and enter it as array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)

Basically these two

```
OFFSET(C:C;0;6*(ROW(1:50)-1))
OFFSET(F:F;0;6*(ROW(1:50)-1))
```

mean that you need to look for "A" in column C and sum column F, then repeat the same for the same combination moved by 6 columns to the right, then again until you repeat it 50 times.

So you need to make sure your structure is always the same (=always move by 6 columns) and then only adjust the `ROW(1:50)` to have total number of your tables in one row instead of 50. And then if you have 50 things to look for (A, B, C,...) you only need to make a columns of these values and change `"A"` to reference these values and copy down formula next to it.

Comment: Thank alot! You are a legend!